# How can I automatically find duplicates amongst my draft in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I sometimes open a Gmail draft in several browsers. This can cause draft to be duplicated. How can I automatically find duplicates among my drafts in Gmail?

Ideally I would like a solution to spot not just exact duplicates, but very similar drafts.

Comment: Are the subject lines for duplicate draft messages likely to be identical?

Comment: Most of the time yes, but not always (empty subjects). A solution working only for identical subjects would still be very useful!

Comment: It's not an answer, but perhaps this might set you in a helpful direction so I'll comment it: In Google Apps Script, the getDraftMessages() method will return an array of your draft messages. Set up a loop that takes the first message in the array and checks its subject against the subject of each remaining message. Add every message with a matching subject to a new array, and after the loop completes do whatever you want with the messages in that new array and also remove those messages from the original array. Continue until the original array is empty (or down to only one message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to automatically find duplicates amongst drafts in Gmail.